# List of thermodynamic properties of various minerals

Tags: mineralogy, thermodynamics

Hi I am looking for a list or a database where I can find the basic thermodynamic data like the standard enthalpy or standard entropy! Do you know of one?

Comment: I found one reference on line, it was published by the USGS in 1962, 60 years ago. It uses Metric units, but old ones, such as calories. [*Thermodynamic properties of minerals*](https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/tei816). Click on the `Document` weblink to download the pdf file.